# Problem with AlarmManager In Android

Tags: android, android-alarms

When I run my application for the first time my alarm is started and it works very well.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Kill_Task.class);  
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                   this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);  

AlarmManager objAlarmManager = 
     (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);  
objAlarmManager.setRepeating(
     AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000, pendingIntent);
```

Now my alarm is continuing in background and I have to switch off my phone. When I switch on my phone my alarm background processing does not start.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** your alarm repeat every second your defined pending intent object . `AlarmManager.setRepeating(...`
**2)** to **cancel/stop** your alarm you've to invoke `objAlarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);` . with a `pendingIntent` that *match* your pending intent that you've define (same **class**, same **action** ... except **extra** data that is not taking into account for comparizon ... see [IntenFilter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.html) to know more about how intent may match another one
**3)** then **cancel** the pending intent itself like `pendingIntent.cancel();` to be sure that pending intent is unusable.